# Download Option for Excel-View

Tags: php, yii, export-to-excel, phpexcel, yii-extensions

I have created  **Test.xlsx** file in application folder, but **i acutally want to give user a option to download it.**
But i want to generate a **temp** excel file that is tranported to client side and after that, **the file will be destroyed**.
I also tired to transfer the run-time generated Test.xlsx file, but due to file permission, i wont be able to do so, that is my Test.xlsx file is for read mode only.

What would be the best method to acheive this? Here is the few lines of code, i have written so far.

```
// code for excel generation from sqlDataProvider.
 $factory = new CWidgetFactory(); 
    Yii::import('ext.eexcelview.EExcelView',true);  
            $widget = $factory->createWidget($this,'EExcelView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataprovider,
                'grid_mode'=>'export',
                'title'=>'Title',
                'creator'=>'TNC',
                'autoWidth'=>true,
                'filename'=>'Test.xlsx',
                'stream'=>false,

                'disablePaging'=>false,
                'exportType'=>'Excel2007',
                'columns'=>array(
                    'First_Name',
                    'Middle_Name',
                    'Last_Name',
        'showTableOnEmpty' => false,
            ));

            $widget->init();
            $widget->run();
```

And for download :

```
$filename = "Test.xlsx";
//@chmod($filename1,0777 );

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel', true);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename));
readfile(Yii::app()->params['secureBaseUrl'].$filename);
```

As i said, this code segment is not working due to file permission of newly generated file.

Comment: You can use [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) inside PHP.

Comment: @Örs I am using it, as you seen in comment line, but not working, permission denied !!

Answer (score 0):

I actually used this extension for one of my projects. This is what I did:

In one of your controllers add this

```
     public function behaviors(){
        return array(
            'toExcel'=>array(
                'class'=>'ext.eexcelview.EExcelBehavior',
            ),
        );
    }
```

Then, create an action in the same controller ie:

```
    public function actionExport(){
        $model=new CLASS_NAME('search');

        $this->toExcel('CLASS_NAME',
        array(
            array(
            'name'=>'ATTRIBUTE',
            'value'=>'$data->ATTRIBUTE."adding some custom string"',
            ),               
        ),
        'Test File', // file name
        array(
            'creator' => 'Zen', // file info
            ),
        'Excel5', // file type
        );
    }
```

Then you should just call `controller/export` in a browser and it will create a temporary excel file for you. You can export to other file formats as well with this extension.

This example will export every record from a table, however you can create a method to return only a partial result or just one row. The behavior works almost exactly like the way `CGridView` does, you can use relations, custom values for rows etc.

Most of this information can be found on the [extension's page](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/toexcel/) as well

Comment: I have sqlDataProvider,so how can i treat this dataprovider ?? or model ??

Comment: I don't know about sqlDataProvider but it should definitely work with CArrayProvider. You can build an array with your results then create an ArrayProvider with said array.